# Random min 'minValue' can not be greater then 'maxValue'

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a small program that will select a random line form a richtextbox and print it out on a label.

I have also tried to make a timer that will display random lines on the label before it stops.

but when I run the program it gives me this error message:

> Random min 'minValue'  can not be greater then 'maxValue'

This is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private int ran;
    private int ranP;
    private int max;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int max = richTextBox1.Lines.Count();
        int ranP = rnd.Next(1, max);
        int ran = 0;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label2.Text = "The Winner is: " + richTextBox1.Lines[ranP];
        ran = rnd.Next(1, 11);
        ranP = rnd.Next(1, max);
        if(ran == 11){
            timer1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The error come on this line in my timer:

> ranP = rnd.Next(1, max);

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: the error message clearly explain what is wrong.

Comment: If the line count of the box is 0, you have a problem. Especially when you hide the field max with the local variable max, in which case your line count can be anything, the field still is 0.

Comment: But how can it do it the first time (when I click the button) but not in the timer? 
It's using the same variables and the list is not changed?

Comment: It would seem that 1 is greater than the variable max.  Did you look at the line in the debugger?

Comment: Many thanks flq I hadn't noticed that :S

and thanks to everyone else for your time! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `button1_Click_1` you declare a local variable `max` which shadows your instance variable `this.max`. When you use `max` in the `timer1_Tick` method it refers to that instance variable which is never assigned to.

Changing the assignment in the `button1_Click_1` to

```
max = richTextBox1.Lines.Count();
```

should help.

Comment: I think that is not problem

Comment: @Selman22 It is: `max` in the timer callback refers to `this.max`. But he never assigns anything to it so it is still 0. The timer is started in the `button1_Click_1` method in which he declares a local variable `max`.